# Marklogic Scaling down in EC2 using cloud formation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, marklogic-10

Currently i am using the Marklogic cloud formation template (https://marklogic-db-template-releases.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/10.0-latest/mlcluster-vpc.template) given by Marklogic itself and launched a cluster (3 nodes in 1 zone) and later I was trying to get familiar with scaling up and scaling down. For Scaling up I updated my cloud formation stack to 4 which brought up another host and created 2 new databases after scaling up. I want to scale down the Marklogic to 3 nodes again from cloud formation but i am seeing an error when I try to scale it down.

Went through the https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/ec2/managing#id_34435 where it says to remove the forest which exist in the host before scaling it down. Any suggestion how to scale down without loosing on data using cloud formation would be great. Thanks in advance.

**Update :**

Error Received : Received response status `[FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: Scaling down the number of nodes per zone by updating the stack is not recommended. Please manually remove unused network interface`

Comment: Can you maybe include the error message in your question?

Comment: Updated the question with the error received when trying to scale down

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message quite clearly states that what you're trying to do is not recommended and since the functionality is calling a custom resource, presumably, the functionality just isn't implemented.

SO you've got the option to create [your own custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) and use that in order to perform the downscaling or to follow the recommendation and downscale manually.